How to set BuildInParallel="false" in a .NET SDK style .csproj?
How can i set BuildInParallel="false" in my .csproj?
In the following example, .csproj has two build targets for net6.0 and net8.0. In default they are run in parallel build processes in Visual Studio Professional 2022 IDE build.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- it makes scripts.zip before build -->
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="call make_zip.bat" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include=".\scripts.zip" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

I have a PreBuild action which makes a zip file from some scripts and python files. This final scripts.zip will be a content of the final build. Because in default, net6.0 and net8.0 are running in parallel build processes, make_zip.bat try to run in parallel for each build but unfortunately it will crash all the time, because same files are busy and can not compressed them twice to a same output zip files in parrallel time.
I can solve this issue if i use dotnet command line with -p:BuildInParallel=false for building. But how can i force to use BuildInParallel=false in my .csproj file in order to use it in Visual Studio Professional 2022 IDE also as a default settings?

Use Build > Project  Dependencies to ensure one project gets built before another.

In Build > Project Dependencies there are no any possibilities to set any multitarget build order for net6.0 and net8.0 build processing. I have a singel csproj which has no any other dependencies but it builds my project two times in parallel because i have <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>.

Create a separate <Project without an Sdk attribute, and add a dependency? eg parts of this example, without compiling any .cs files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-msbuild-project-file-from-scratch?view=vs-2022

Based on your description, I was able to successfully reproduce the problem you encountered:

If you want to set BuildInParallel="false" in .csproj, you only need to add <BuildInParallel>false</BuildInParallel>:

